# I got an error in pypsark, that states: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: pyspark

What I did is I tried to `groupby` and `collect_list`:

Data:

```
id dates       quantity
-- -----       -----
12 2012-03-02  1
32 2012-02-21  4
43 2012-03-02  4
5  2012-12-02  5
42 2012-12-02  7
21 2012-31-02  9
3  2012-01-02  5
2  2012-01-02  5
3  2012-01-02  7
2  2012-01-02  1
3  2012-01-02  3
21 2012-01-02  6
21 2012-03-23  5
21 2012-03-24  3
21 2012-04-25  1
21 2012-07-23  6
21 2012-01-02  8
```

Code:

```
new_df = df.groupby('id').agg(F.collect_list("dayid"),F.collect_list("quantity"))
```

Comment: please upload more of your code

Comment: also please better format your data from and use code blocks when pasting code

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work fine for me, only question I have is you have used `dayid` as column in the `collect_list` rest all looks fine.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
sc = spark.sparkContext

dataset1 = [{'id' : 12,'dates' : '2012-03-02','quantity' : 1},
  {'id' : 32,'dates' : '2012-02-21','quantity' : 4},
  {'id' : 12,'dates' : '2012-03-02','quantity' : 1},
  {'id' : 32,'dates' : '2012-02-21','quantity' : 4}]

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(dataset1)
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1)
df1.show()
+----------+---+--------+
|     dates| id|quantity|
+----------+---+--------+
|2012-03-02| 12|       1|
|2012-02-21| 32|       4|
|2012-03-02| 12|       1|
|2012-02-21| 32|       4|
+----------+---+--------+

new_df = df1.groupby('id').agg(F.collect_list("dayid"),F.collect_list("quantity"))
+---+----------------+----------------------+
| id|collect_list(id)|collect_list(quantity)|
+---+----------------+----------------------+
| 32|        [32, 32]|                [4, 4]|
| 12|        [12, 12]|                [1, 1]|
+---+----------------+----------------------+
```